# AWS automatically route EC2 instances to domain

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, amazon-route53

When firing up multiple new EC2 instances, how do I make these new machines automatically accessible publicly on my domain ****.example.com?

So if I fire up two instances that would normally have a public DNS of

`ec2-12-34-56.compute-1.amazonaws.com` and `ec2-12-34-57.compute-1.amazonaws.com`

instead be `ec2-12-34-56.example.com` and `ec2-12-34-57.example.com`

Is there a way to use a VPC and Route53 or do I need to run my own DNS server?

Comment: Route 53 is a DNS service. You can add a record in that, or write a script to automatically add a record for you.

Comment: You can create VPC specific DNS zone in Route53. While creating the zone, Change the type to VPC and the select the VPC from the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you want to do this in the easiest way. You don't need a VPC

First we need to set up an elastic ip address. This is going to be the connection point between the Route53 DNS service (which you should absolutely use) and the instance. Go into the EC2 menu of the management console, click elastic ip and click create. Create it into EC2-Classic (option will pop up). Remember this ip.

Now go into Route53. Create a hosted zone for your domain. Go into this zone and create a record set for staging.example.com (or whatever your prefix is). Leave it as an A record (default) and put the elastic IP in the textbox.

Note you now need to go into your registrar login (e.g. goDaddy) and replace the nameservers with the ones shown on the NS record. They will look like:
ns-1776.awsdns-30.co.uk. 
ns-123.awsdns-15.com. 
ns-814.awsdns-37.net. 
ns-1500.awsdns-59.org

and you will be able to see them once you create a hosted zone.

Once you've done this it will redirect all requests to that IP address. But it isn't associated with anything. Once you have created an instance, go back into the elastic ip menu and associate it with the instance. Now all requests to that domain will go to that instance. To change just re-associate. Make sure your security zones allow all traffic (or at least HTTP) or it will seem like it doesn't work.

This is not good cloud architecture, but it will get the job done. Better cloud architecture would be making the route point to a load balancer, and attaching the instance to the load balancer. This should all be done in a VPC. It may not be worth your time if you are doing development.